# Content Porter 2013 SP1 Import Issue

Tags: content-porter-2013

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and Content Porter 2013 SP1. While importing I am getting the below error message. Yesterday the import was working fine. Can anyone please help to resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

**[Error] System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException: Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D02B)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ReceiveTransaction(UInt32 propgationTokenSize, Byte[] propgationToken, IntPtr managedIdentifier, Guid& transactionIdentifier, OletxTransactionIsolationLevel& isolationLevel, ITransactionShim& transactionShim)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[] propagationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[] propagationToken)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Promote(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction transaction, Byte[] whereabouts)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.GetConnection()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.GetStoredProcedureCommand(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IIdentifiableObjectDataMapper.IsExistingObject(TcmUri id)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.IsExistingObject(String uri)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.StronglyTypedFilter.ValidateLinks(Session session)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.WorkflowManager.GetListProcessDefinitionsData(ProcessDefinitionsFilter& filter)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.WorkflowManager.GetProcessDefinitions(ProcessDefinitionsFilter filter)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.AbortErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.MappingsResolver.UpdateProcessDefinitionMappings(Repository publication)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.SaveItem(IdentifiableObject item, IdentifiableObjectData deltaObject)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.UpdateImportAction.Perform(IdentifiableObjectData itemData)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItems(IList`1 items, Boolean specialGroupImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.Import(String packageName)
   [Information] Transactional import failed at 4/16/2014 12:05:00 AM. No changes were committed to Tridion Content Manager.
**

Comment: Is your CM connected to database? As looking at stacktrace it seems that Content Manager can't connect to database. Is everything fine with your CM?

Answer (score 3):

Try the below solution

The DTCtester, a tool provided by Microsoft, can be used to test distributed transaction against a specified Microsoft SQL Server instance. Additional information can be found in the following Knowledge Base article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293799/en-us

We have registered similar issues before. This was caused by conflicting Group Policy settings applied via the Active Directory and/or by altering the local security templates. In addition, enabling the built-in windows firewall might prevent MSDTC from working. Details can be found on:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306843 - How to troubleshoot MS DTC firewall issues

Comment: I think you are also not able to create publication in your CMS, just confirm this.

Comment: Hi Nash, i am able to create publication in my CMS.

Comment: Ok, try to follow the above steps......